# Bootstrap navbar opacitiy using scrolling-nav js

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, opacity

Im using scrolling-nav-js [Scrolling nav](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/) to animate padding and fix my navbar to the top of my page and i want to give the navbar a subtle opacity animation. How can i add the transition to change the opacity property?

I have the following code in the JS and the CSS files:

```js
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});

//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind :) adding this is perfect.

```css
transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease-in-out,opacity .5s ease-in-out;
```

and

```css
.top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
```